# Weird behavior for a property bound to the 'SelectedItem' of a WPF Combobox 

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

When binding a property to the `SelectedItem` of a WPF Combobox, I would expect to see that property setter get called every time the combobox's selection is changed. I'm not seeing that.

Should the Combobox be calling the bound `SelectedItem`'s property setter when the selection is changed?

**Addition**: I actually have the binding partially there: the property getter gets called and the property setter gets called once when the combobox is first loaded/selected and never called again upon later selection changes.

One thing I noticed is that when I put the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = True` in the combobox entry in Xaml, the setter gets called once upon combobox loading/initial selection, but never again. When I remove that combobox attribute, the setter *never* gets called. Very strange.

Also, I'm referring to a view model property, not a dependency property. At least I didn't set it up as a dependency property. I'm new to this (Surprise!), so any more nuggets of info regarding this subject would be most appreciated.

xaml Code:

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="300" Margin="5,0,0,5"
   ItemsSource="{Binding KeywordCollectionTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding KeywordCollectionType, Mode=TwoWay}"
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

ViewModel Code (The Binded Attributes):

```
 public Collection<string> KeywordCollectionTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _KeywordCollectionTypes;
        }
    }

public string KeywordCollectionType
    {
        get
        {
            return _KeywordCollectionType;
        }
        set
        {
            _KeywordCollectionType = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("KeywordCollectionType");
        }
    }
```

One more bit of info is that the combobox is within a `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`, so could this strange update behavior be related to it being within a row details?

Comment: I can't recall if the ComboBox SelectedItem defaults to two-way binding, but you might try putting `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding expression.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets from your code, without that it will be tough to find the exact problem/solution.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you take the code that you've just posted above and create a minimal WPF project that just includes a window, a combo box, and a view model with only those properties implemented, the combo box will work.

Comment: I have that feeling as well, and i'm wondering if this has to do with the fact that the combobox is within a rowdetailstemplate of a datagrid. It's almost like the row details loses its data context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem I was having. in the binding statement to the combobox's SelectedItem, I needed to put: "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"

Like this:

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="300" Margin="5,0,0,5"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding KeywordCollectionTypes, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding KeywordCollectionType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Here's the thread that got me to the fix:

[Problem with data binding (Using the MVVM pattern) to a WPF Combobox within a DataGrid's RowDetailsTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214572/)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something wrong.  From a current project of mine:

```
<ComboBox
   ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConfiguration, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The `SelectedConfiguration` property setter gets called every time the selected item changes.

**Edit**

I'm assuming that your object isn't a `DependencyObject`, and that the property you're binding to isn't a dependency property.  If it is a dependency property, then as DK observes, binding will update the property value by calling `SetValue` and will bypass the CLR property accessor; if you want to insert logic into that control flow, reference a callback method when you register the dependency property.

Comment: since my answer was about DP, I'll remove it

Answer (score 0):

this is how you bind a combobox's selected item to your data model....

```
 <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyValue}"/>
```

where MyValue is a property of your DataContext/Data Model.

if you want to bind a different control, such as TextBlock, to the selected item, here is a small example...

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" SelectedIndex="0">
   <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"/>
```

here, the text block will update whenever the ComboBox selection changes.